# Matplotlib - why is only the last bar adjusting width in each part?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble understanding why when I change the width from 0.2 to 0.5, only the far right series (group_c) changes. has anyone run into this?

Picture included for reference of graph output.

- a - o are just rand ints

```
group_a = (a,b,c,d,e)
group_b = (f,g,h,i,j)
group_c = (k,l,m,n,o)
width = 0.5
x = np.arange(5)

#I think it is something in here, but not sure what
plt.bar(x-0.2, group_a, width, color = 'cyan')
plt.bar(x, group_b, width, color = 'orange')
plt.bar(x+0.2, group_c, width, color = 'green')

plt.xticks(x, ['1','2','3','4','5'])
plt.xlabel("quarter")
plt.ylabel('%')
plt.legend(['Group A','Group B','Group C'])
plt.show()
```

[picture of output]

[image: 1]

Comment: The width of all bars is 0.5 and the offset on the x-axis is 0.2, so they are shifted to the right by 0.2. To make this the same, I would need to increase the offset value to at least 0.5.

Comment: Is there a way to evenly space them out and still keep the three together? for example, I want the group a, group b, and group c values for "1" to be together, and for "2" to be together, but separated by space

Comment: @r-beginners sorry forgot to tag in first comment still learning how to use stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars are just overlapping because the offset is less than the widths of the bars. By changing the order you add them to the plot you can see that the overlap differently.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

group_a = 5*[20]
group_b = 5*[40]
group_c = 5*[100]
width = 0.5
x = np.arange(5)

#I think it is something in here, but not sure what
plt.bar(x-0.2, group_a, width, color = 'cyan')
plt.bar(x+0.2, group_c, width, color = 'green')
plt.bar(x, group_b, width, color = 'orange')

plt.xticks(x, ['1','2','3','4','5'])
plt.xlabel("quarter")
plt.ylabel('%')
plt.legend(['Group A','Group B','Group C'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to evenly space them out and still keep the three together? for example, I want the group a, group b, and group c values for "1" to be together, and for "2" to be together, but separated by space

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the width is correct, but the bars are just behind each other. Perhaps, by adding some transparency with alpha you can see it clearly.

```
group_a = (a,b,c,d,e)
group_b = (f,g,h,i,j)
group_c = (k,l,m,n,o)
width = 0.5
x = np.arange(5)
plt.bar(x-0.2, group_a, width, color = 'cyan')
plt.bar(x, group_b, width, alpha = .5, color = 'orange')
plt.bar(x+0.2, group_c, width, alpha = .1, color = 'green')
plt.xticks(x, ['1','2','3','4','5'])
plt.xlabel("quarter")
plt.ylabel('%')
plt.legend(['Group A','Group B','Group C'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to evenly space them out and still keep the three together? for example, I want the group a, group b, and group c values for "1" to be together, and for "2" to be together, but separated by space